# How to call existing Cloud functions from React Firebase app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

New to Firebase. We are creating a React JS frontend application and deploying to Firebase Hosting. We need to integrate with some existing Google Cloud Functions that have been deployed in Python.

I've seen from the Google documentation on using the Firebase SDK to call functions deployed through Firebase but not sure how I would integrate with the existing GCP functions. I assume I can just use something like Axios to call the GCP functions. If there are any alternatives, I'd be interested to know.

Comment: Are those functions HTTP triggered?

Comment: As in I can call them from browser/command line? Then yes.

Comment: You can use any library or built-in command of your environment to call a [HTTPS function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#invoke_an_http_function). Axios is a common-used library, but `fetch` and even good old `XMLHttpRequest` would work fine too. Since there are a lot of options, and not clear best one, recommending any of them is off-topic on Stack Overflow. I recommend picking the one that seems reasonable to you (Axios it seems), trying to get it to work, and posting back with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you get stuck.

Comment: Great thanks Frank, will use axios. Im hoping that I can still use the Firebase [hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrite-functions) rewrites section so I can call the existing API from the Firebase app domain. I'll have a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `axios` to call the Cloud functions

```js
import axios from 'axios';

axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://us-central1-PROJECT_NAME.cloudfunctions.net/test',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  }
})
.then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Great thanks Kundan.